# Работа с рандомными числами

Tags: javascript, jquery, случайные-числа

Как написать скрипт на JS, чтобы он выполнял следующую задачу:

> Каждые 10 минут к числу прибавляется еще одно число от 0 до 20
>   (начальное число - 0). Все действия должны выполняться **без
>   обновления страницы**.

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос еще раз, как будто Вы разговариваете с людьми без телепатических способностей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const interval = 777; // милисекунды
const min = 3;
const max = 20;

let number = 0;
setInterval(() => output.innerHTML = number += min + ~~(Math.random()*(max - min)), interval);
```

```html
<div id=output></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, здорово очень, а реально Darth сделать что бы цифры были челыми и обновлялось все без выведения других чисел? то есть за место старой появлалась новая

Comment: @GorodBox обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое, как раз тот результат что искал

Comment: Тогда сделай доброе дело человеку и отметь как ответ :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы. Очень помогли. Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли во второй код добавить код что бы таймер запускался единожды, то есть при обновлении страницы данные не сбивались.